# List of loaded iptables modules

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

Is there any convenient way to show loaded iptables module list? I can show installed modules by listing `/lib/iptables/` (or `/lib64/iptables/`) directory but I need active modules list.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Loaded *iptables* modules can be found in **/proc/net/ip_tables_matches** proc filesystem entry.

```
cat /proc/net/ip_tables_matches
```

In PHP I can access the loaded *iptables* modules by loading and exploding file contents:

```
$content = file_get_contents('/proc/net/ip_tables_matches');
$modules = explode("\n", $content);
```

Of course it requires proc filesystem to be mounted (Most GNU Linux distros mount it by default)

Comment: It seems that one should check the result of `file_get_contents()` because it can return `false`.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look in the following directory (replace per your kernel version):

```
ls /lib/modules/2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64/kernel/net/netfilter/
```

You can load the module using (dropping the `.ko` as listed in the directory):

```
modprobe nf_conntrack_ftp
```

Alternatively, you can ensure it's loaded at boot by adding it to:

```
/etc/sysconfig/iptables-config (RHEL/CENTOS) 

IPTABLES_MODULES="nf_conntrack_ftp"
```

This seems to be poorly documented.

Comment: I really appreciate the note regarding how to load it on boot. Woauh. Spent too much time searching for this.

Answer (score 5):

This is a really old post but here we go:

```
# lsmod | grep ip
```

shows a list of loaded modules, which I think most are related to iptables...
`/proc/net/ip_tables_matches` doesn't show modules (at least not in RHEL 6)

Answer (score 5):

Try this for a fast overview on the netfilter modules present on your system, here a one-liner for pasting:

```
for i in /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/net/netfilter/*; do echo -e "\e[33;1m$(basename "$i")\e[0m"; strings "$i" | \grep -e description -e depends| sed -e 's/Xtables: //g' -e 's/=/: /g' -e 's/depends=/depends on: /g'; echo; done
```

Again for readability, with added newlines:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/net/netfilter/*
do 
    echo -e "\e[33;1m$(basename "$i")\e[0m"
    strings "$i" | \grep -e description -e depends | sed -e 's/Xtables: //g' -e 's/=/: /g' -e 's/depends=/depends on: /g'
    echo
done
```

Filename will appear in yellow, from which you can guess if the module in question exists or not. Description and dependencies are the next two lines below.

This will not cover everything (because this would be too easy, ofc). Only looking up the modules manually, to see if they exist, gives you 100% accurate information.

```
iptables -m <match/module name> --help
```

If a module exists on your system, at the end of the help text you will get some info on how to use it:

```
ctr-014# iptables -m limit --help
iptables v1.4.14

Usage: iptables -[ACD] chain rule-specification [options]
       iptables -I chain [rulenum] rule-specification [options]
  

...


[!] --version   -V              print package version.

limit match options:
--limit avg                     max average match rate: default 3/hour
                                [Packets per second unless followed by 
                                /sec /minute /hour /day postfixes]
--limit-burst number            number to match in a burst, default 5
ctr-014#
```

It the module is not present on your system:

```
ctr-014# iptables -m iplimit --help
iptables v1.4.14: Couldn't load match `iplimit':No such file or directory

Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
ctr-014#
```

Answer (score 2):

As Gonio has suggested lsmod lists all loaded kernel modules, but grepping "ip" won't give you all iptables modules.

I would rather use

```
lsmod|grep -E "nf_|xt_|ip"
```

and still, I'm not sure the list will be complete.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative method, this can also be done with a Python script.

First make sure you have the iptc library.
    sudo pip install --upgrade python-iptables

(Assuming Python3 is your version)

```
import iptc
table = iptc.Table(iptc.Table.FILTER)
for chain in table.chains:
    print("------------------------------------------")
    print("Chain ", chain.name)
    for rule in chain.rules:
        print("Rule ", "proto", rule.protocol, "src:", rule.src, "dst:" , rule.dst, "in:", rule.in_interface, "out:", rule.out_interface)
        print("Matches:")
        for match in rule.matches:
            print(match.name)
        print("Target:")
        print(rule.target.name)
print("------------------------------------------")
```